# PropertyGrid drop down list vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How do you filter PropertyGrid dropdown list in WinForms vb.net?
I have PropertyGrid dropdown list pre-filled 10 - 20 items and no idea how to remove at list 11 items.

Any ideas? Regards.

[image]

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the list repeating the items:
 `command.Parameters.Clear()`
this will clear the list in every post back

Comment: the problem is that after that, I am unable to add any new dynamically items e.g command.Parameters.add("city")

Comment: The new added dynamically items are not shown in PropertyGrid

Comment: your command should be like :  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city)

Comment: I use this method to build PropertyGrid: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa302326.aspx

Comment: Your method works fine, I did forgot to refresh the PropertyGrid.